# Refresh route with next-routes

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I use `next-routes` module on my `NextJS` project. My routing work good, but if i hard refresh the current page, express return an 404 error.

I think the problem is not good server configuration, but i don't find any information on `next-routes` docs :/

```
app.prepare().then(() => {
  express()
    .use(handler)
    .listen(port);
});
```

My routes.js :

```
const routes = require('next-routes')

module.exports = routes()
.add('index', '/', 'index')
.add('register', '/inscription', 'register');
```

Any one have idea ?

Thank you community !

Comment: Please add your `routes()` code.

Comment: I've update my first post :)

Comment: Does express print any logs when it sends the 404 response? Are they any different before the hard refresh is done?